# Deploy Laravel docker project on a Linux server

Tags: laravel, windows, docker, deployment, centos

I'm working on Laravel projects with Docker containers (Php-FPM, Nginx, xdebug, ...) under Windows OS + Netbeans. Docker simplifies life for all projects at start.

But as many, I need to frequently deploy my work on internal TEST servers (centOS 8) and further on PROD servers (centOS 8).

Repo are on SASS GitLab.

What can you advise me as a method for deploying my laravel projects with docker containers on TEST / PROD servers knowing that they are under centOS and that my Docker containers works on a Linux OS that escapes me.

Are there any compatibility issues between docker containers and another OS Linux Server?

Should I create SSH tunnels to execute Rsync scripts from Windows (DEV) to Linux (TEST & PROD) to deploy my projects?

What are the up to date methods?

MAJ : My wishes would be to reuse docker containers on TEST a PROD centOS servers in order to benefit without have to reconfigure any web servers and so on ...

Thanks for your help,

Best regards